# Switch OrientDB Teleporter source schema

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-etl

I'am testing the OrientDB to see if we can change our RDBMs and switch to it. I see that the Teleporter tool can grab the data from the production server and make a initial graph with the data.
The issue I have is that I neet to connect to one service an change/switch the schema/user to another. We connect with a user with only readonly access to production and see the data en other_users/us_mpa

The backend is oracle rac and the connection string is to a service.

Teleporter is currently connecting to the DB but it import only the table under my user (wich is the correct behaviour) and I need to tell it to switch to another schema.

Thanks

Comment: Why you can't just use a user with full access to the DB?

Comment: The DB server administration is responsability of another area. The user that has full access to the DB is only allowed from the ip address of the app server. This is due to a security reasons.
Other user can connect from the vpn only in readonly mode.

Comment: If your user is read-only I think it's impossible. You may ask to rise up your user permissions and open network to the new machine where OrientDB is installed temporarily, while you will be running Teleporter.

Comment: Please, consider to add a new parameter like -jschema so we can specify wich to use.
In particular, in the Oracle session it is solved executing 

ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=xxxxx

Comment: You can make a request on github.